# TypeORM and Vue class components

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, typeorm

I'm working on a full-stack app:

- Backend: Node, Typescript, TypeORM
- Frontend: Typescript, Vue (using Vue CLI and class components)

I'm trying to share my models with the frontend using TypeORM's [shim for webpack](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/extra/typeorm-model-shim.js#L16-L21). This is largely working. However, when I use an entity type in a component method signature, I get an error:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";

import { Family } from "@/entity/Family";

@Component()
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  newFamily: Family | null = null; // <-- *Using Family here compiles and works.*

  @Watch("newFamily")
  onNewFamilyChanged(val: Family, oldVal: Family): void { // <-- *This throws the error below.*
    ...
  }
```

Error:

```
This dependency was not found:

* typeorm in ./src/entity/Family.ts

To install it, you can run: npm install --save typeorm
```

If I switch the `Family` argument types on `onNewFamilyChanged` to `any`, then everything works again. I'm not sure where to go from here, but I suspect some processing or transformation carried out by vue-class-component is bypassing the shim?